# helpme to recognize that kind of date is and convert mysql date with PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

I have a problem I'm generating an array with PHPExcel but to insert the date on the base gives an error because the date is in excel format and need mysql here is the code used

```
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load( $targetFile );

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$lastRow = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
$dataExcel = array();
for ( $i = 2; $i <= $lastRow; $i++ ){
  $dataExcel[$i]['usr_date_entry'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('K'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
}
```

´echo $dataExcel[0]['usr_date_entry']; // return 21774´

Comment: "when inserting the date I get a date format and I need excel to mysql" I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: Show what date format you're getting!

Comment: echo $dataExcel[0]['usr_date_entry']; // return 21774

Comment: Either use `getFormattedValue()` rather than just `getValue()`; or use the Date/Time conversion functions in the Shared DateTime class to convert it from an Excel timestamp to a unix timestamp or PHP DateTime object... you can then use standard PHP date formatting functions to convert it to an appropriate format for insertion in your database